# Error in implementing algorithm for C ++: redefinition error & The file is invalid or corrupt

Tags: c, algorithm

I have received the Derek algorithm in C++

it's code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC
#include<pthread.h>
#define NR_THREAD 2

struct dekker
{
    char flag[2];
    int turn;
};

void dekker_lock(struct dekker *, int);
void dekker_unlock(struct dekker *, int);

static struct dekker dlock;
static unsigned long result_sum;
void dekker_lock(struct dekker *d, int thid)
{
    d->flag[thid] = 1;
    while (d->flag[!thid])
    {
        d->flag[thid] = 0;
        while (d->turn != thid) { (void)0; }
        d->flag[thid] = 1;
    }
}
void dekker_unlock(struct dekker *d, int thid)
{
    d->flag[thid] = 0;
    d->turn = !thid;
}
static void *thread_routine(void *arg)
{
    int i;
    int thid = *(int *)arg;
    for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        dekker_lock(&dlock, thid);
        result_sum++;
        dekker_unlock(&dlock, thid);
    }
    return NULL;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t pth[NR_THREAD];
    for (i = 0; i < NR_THREAD; i++) { pthread_create(&pth[i], NULL,             
thread_routine, &i); }
    for (i = 0; i < NR_THREAD; i++) { pthread_join(pth[i], NULL); }
    printf("result = %lu\n", result_sum);
    return 0;
}
```

and i running this code. I get an error : Timespec redefinition error.

So I searched and got answers : Add between library declarations `#define HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC`

When I add the above sentence and execute it, I also get error. : The file is invalid or corrupt. Can not read from 0x288.

I want to know how to solution this problem. And this solution would be short and simple sentences.

Comment: running the code or trying to compile the code?

Comment: I suspect you shouldn't be setting HAVE_STRUCT_TIMESPEC, that should be set by the header that actually provides it

Comment: Check the file that the compiler claims to be corrupt. Is it corrupt?

Comment: Is it C or C++ ? Title say C++ but tags say C.

Comment: i add tag c++.  By the way, Has been changed.